# How to get top contributors by the number of added lines between two Git revisions?

Tags: git

`git shortlog` can output top contributors by the number of commits. How to get top contributors by the number of added lines though?

Comment: I guess this is more or less an usecase of difflame: https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame